# Add values ​to ListView without repeating them

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using C# with Xamarin Forms and I don't know how to add values ​​to a ListView without repeating them.

I haven't tried anything yet

InventoryPerRowModel.Add(new InventoryPerRow { IntRow = Convert.ToInt32(Row.Text), IntPlants = Convert.ToInt32(TotalPlants.Text), IntPlantsUnusable = Convert.ToInt32(PlantsUnusable.Text) });

var InventoryPorSurcoModelOrdenado = InventoryPorSurcoModel.OrderBy(x => x.IntSurco).ToList();
MyListView.ItemsSource = InventoryByPathSortedModel;

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  You haven't shown us any code that demonstrates what you're doing so it's difficult to recommend a solution.  The short answer is to "check if a value is in the list before adding it" but since, again, you haven't shown us any specifics, its difficult to give you a concrete example.

Comment: Ok ready  I hope you can help me greetings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Do you want to display some data array on `ListView`(with some `Label`s and `Entry` for the item) and want to edit the value of the `Entry `, but need to make sure the value of it is not exist on the array, right?

Answer (score 0):

if your data looks like this

```
ObservableCollection<int> myData = new ObservableCollection<int>();

myData.Add(1);
...
myData.Add(10);

myListView.ItemsSource = myData;
```

then when you want to add a new value

```
private void AddToList(int i)
{

   if (myData.Contains(i))
   {
      // already in the list, throw an error
   }
   else 
   {
     myData.Add(i);
   }
}
```

Comment: Excuse me, but to be able to use the AddToList method from a button, what value do I give to AddToList(HERE);

Comment: the value/object you want to add to the list.  My example uses `int` - you'll need to modify accordingly to fit your data

Comment: Ok I understand, I applied the code that you gave me and when adding it does not show me anything in the ListView it is worth mentioning that in the listview I add 3 data: Id, Number, Age through the Binding in the XAML, Exmaple one of them Text="{Binding IntNumber}

Comment: If you need additional help you need to update your post to show what you’ve done.  And please format your post so the code is readable

Comment: Well, if it's something tedious, look at the values ​​that I fill in the ListView, first they are in a TextBox Each one and Before all I wanted to put the data that the TextBox has Id.Text in an array where I was saving them together with an if where if in The array had already added an Id number example 10 when I wanted to save another id with the number 10 again, it would show me a message that the value is already inside the array but I couldn't do the same with the HashSet, I don't know if you can help me with that

Comment: Please read my last comment.  And read [mcve].  Posting a description of your code is not helpful.  Posting the actual **relevant** bits are.

Comment: Well I wanted to ask another question but I can ask it right here to be clearer how I could create an array and fill it by means of a textBox with a value of type int, where when trying to enter the same value for the second time a message appears saying that the value is already It is inside the array and I did not add it, I hope you understand me thank you

Comment: That is **exactly** what my answer shows.  How to check a list/array or other IEnumerable to see if a value already exists and add it if it doesn’t

Answer (score 0):

Best way - use ObservableCollection (Jasons answer).
Is not well, but working:

```
var InventoryPorSurcoModelOrdenado = InventoryPorSurcoModel  
    .OrderBy(x => x.IntSurco)  
    .Distinct() 
    .ToList();
```

Comment: dude i tried but it didnt work :(

Comment: it is because you should implement compare function for InventoryPerRow. Override Equals function and GetHashCode - it is min action. Your class compare by ref now, but not by values

Comment: UPD: sorry, your code confuse me. You are set different values to ItemSource, than values that you try to filter. Please, pay attention on it